# ATM proble in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have to write a code which receives (amount, bills, n). bills is a tuple of available cash bills, and n is the number of times you have to use the bill exactly in order to receive the amount.  for example: atm_rec(70,(5,10),8) it must return true because we can generate amount 70 with 8 bills of 5 and 10

Comment: i must use recursion in the code please help me

Comment: Maybe you should ask [your friend](https://codedump.io/share/PIdx8Fv1IkzD/1/calculating-a-simple-39atm39-using-memoization-on-python)

Comment: We're not here to do your homework. If you've written some code and tried something that's not working, please share that and let us know how we can help.

Comment: how can i use memoization so the function is atm_mem(amount,bills,n,memo=None)

Answer (score -3):

```
def atm_rec(amount, bills, n):
    if not n and not amount: return True
    return any(atm_rec(amount-bill, bills, n-1) for bill in bills if bill<=amount)
```

Comment: what is the role of any?

Comment: @קוסיימסארוה: you have put absolutely no research effort into asking this, or your original question. Perhaps googling `python any` would have taken you to [the official documentation which explains exactly what you ask](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

Comment: i have the same problem but with memoization how can i use memoization so the function is atm_mem(amount,bills,n,memo=None)